# I am having problems installing the openmpi package in the spack installation phase, how can I proceed?

Tags: gcc, stack, mpi, openmpi, fenics

I have problems regarding the configuration and installation phase of openmpi starting from the command:
`spack install hdf5`
for the installation of spack.

Keep getting the following output:

```
[...]
 No patches needed for openmpi
==> openmpi: Executing phase: 'autoreconf'
==> openmpi: Executing phase: 'configure'
==> Error: ProcessError: Command exited with status 1:
    '/var/folders/8_/wztdc3v56hg9j4qj_fv9b6vm0000gp/T/lorenzomarta/spack-stage/spack-stage-openmpi-4.1.2-dt7kysg3arqzxcey3isivwhq2gjrpwiq/spack-src/configure' '--prefix=/Users/lorenzomarta/spack/opt/spack/darwin-monterey-m1/apple-clang-13.0.0/openmpi-4.1.2-dt7kysg3arqzxcey3isivwhq2gjrpwiq' '--enable-shared' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-builtin-atomics' '--enable-static' '--without-pmi' '--with-zlib=/Users/lorenzomarta/spack/opt/spack/darwin-monterey-m1/apple-clang-13.0.0/zlib-1.2.11-geghxlnypciim4i5a3v2kk6xlnt7coym' '--enable-mpi1-compatibility' '--without-psm' '--without-mxm' '--without-ucx' '--without-xpmem' '--without-fca' '--without-knem' '--without-psm2' '--without-cma' '--without-verbs' '--without-ofi' '--without-hcoll' '--without-cray-xpmem' '--without-tm' '--without-loadleveler' '--without-alps' '--without-lsf' '--without-sge' '--without-slurm' '--disable-memchecker' '--with-libevent=/Users/lorenzomarta/spack/opt/spack/darwin-monterey-m1/apple-clang-13.0.0/libevent-2.1.12-73xjwogw6nqpuldlylbmoigwmr226opr' '--with-hwloc=/Users/lorenzomarta/spack/opt/spack/darwin-monterey-m1/apple-clang-13.0.0/hwloc-2.7.0-ozodgqskus55yycodml6yamfm3zlp7bp' '--disable-java' '--disable-mpi-java' '--with-gpfs=no' '--without-cuda' '--enable-wrapper-rpath' '--disable-wrapper-runpath' '--disable-mpi-cxx' '--disable-cxx-exceptions'

2 errors found in build log:
     358    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
     359    checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
     360    checking if .proc/endp is needed... no
     361    checking directive for setting text section... .text
     362    checking directive for exporting symbols... .globl
     363    checking for objdump... objdump
  >> 364    checking if .note.GNU-stack is needed... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: error: 'conftest.o': Invalid/
            Unsupported object file format
     365    no
     366    checking suffix for labels... :
     367    checking prefix for global symbol labels... _
     368    checking prefix for lsym labels... L
     369    checking prefix for function in .type...
     370    checking if .size is needed... no

     ...

     386    * execute.  Note that this is likely not a problem with Open MPI,
     387    * but a problem with the local compiler installation.  More
     388    * information (including exactly what command was given to the
     389    * compiler and what error resulted when the command was executed) is
     390    * available in the config.log file in the Open MPI build directory.
     391    **********************************************************************
  >> 392    configure: error: Could not run a simple Fortran program.  Aborting.

See build log for details:
  /var/folders/8_/wztdc3v56hg9j4qj_fv9b6vm0000gp/T/lorenzomarta/spack-stage/spack-stage-openmpi-4.1.2-dt7kysg3arqzxcey3isivwhq2gjrpwiq/spack-build-out.txt

==> Warning: Skipping build of hdf5-1.12.1-76nex7zsw662gm5rjdkxmnspagvnzjrd since openmpi-4.1.2-dt7kysg3arqzxcey3isivwhq2gjrpwiq failed
==> Error: hdf5-1.12.1-76nex7zsw662gm5rjdkxmnspagvnzjrd: Package was not installed
==> Error: Installation request failed.  Refer to reported errors for failing package(s).
(base) Mac:~ lorenzomarta$ spack install -v openmpi@4.0.0 %gcc@5.5
==> Error: No compilers with spec gcc@5.5 found
Run 'spack compiler find' to add compilers or 'spack compilers' to see which compilers are already recognized by spack.
(base) Mac:~ lorenzomarta$ spack install -v openmpi@4.0.0 %gcc@5.5
==> Error: No compilers with spec gcc@5.5 found
Run 'spack compiler find' to add compilers or 'spack compilers' to see which compilers are already recognized by spack.
```

(I'm working with mac with m1 processor)

From the spack compilers I get this output:

```
spack compilers
==> Available compilers
-- apple-clang monterey-aarch64 ---------------------------------
apple-clang@13.0.0

-- clang monterey-aarch64 ---------------------------------------
clang@6.0.0
```

My goal is actually to install FEniCS (DOLFINx) and from what I found online I saw that to do this you first need to install spack and so I tried.
Among the various packages I was installing I found the problem indicated in openmpi. I don't know how to proceed if I need to download something else or get around the problem with another procedure.

Comment: the error message is almost self explanatory: your compiler install is busted and this is not an Open MPI issue. look at `/var/folders/8_/wztdc3v56hg9j4qj_fv9b6vm0000gp/T/lorenzomarta/spack-stage/spack-stage-openmpi-4.1.2-dt7kysg3arqzxcey3isivwhq2gjrpwiq/spack-src/config.log` to find some more info on what went wrong.

Comment: anyway, consider using `brew` since that might be much easier and faster https://macappstore.org/fenics/

Comment: Unfortunately I can only find a config.log file on my mac which is in a different location than the one indicated.
Furthermore I also tried with the other procedure indicated, that is the one indicated in the link to proceed with an installation via `brew install fenics` and here too I encountered problems, this is the output obtained:

Comment: ```==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 3 formulae.
Running `brew update --preinstall`...

Warning: No available formula with the name "fenics".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```